# Calling back jquery function after knockout dom manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, knockout.js

I'm fairly new to Knockout and I am trying to use a jquery plugin which applies custom styling to certain elements. But since I have a page that gets the content from the ajax call and all the elements are build on the fly by knockout the initial jquery function call has no idea that there are any elements on the page, so no styling is applied on those elements.

So what I'm asking is how do I callback a jquery function after knockout is done manipulating the elements (DOM)?

Right now I'm calling jquery function as following:-

```
$(document).on("load",function(){
    $(".element").callPlugin("add-style");
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`applyBindings` is synchronous, so you could  call `callPlugin` after `ko.applyBindings(VM)` (in the next line).

```
ko.applyBindings(VM);
 $(".element").callPlugin("add-style");
```

Or, you could use [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) if you're updating your UI multiple times. Assuming `.element` is an `<div>` (It could also be anything else), your tag would look like this :

```
<div class="element" data-bind="text: 'This is just some text which KO will bind',
                                updateUI: true">
This text will change. Wait for it..
</div>
```

Notice the `updateUI` in `data-bind`. This is the corresponding JS code for it :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.updateUI = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext){          
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
        $(".element").callPlugin("add-style");
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever the associated observable changes value.
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
        $(".element").callPlugin("update-style"); // just saying
    }
};
```

This will make your plugin initialise and update automatically when any changes are done to the DOM.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Marking this as correct because this explained with nice example. I did use custom-binding and it worked. Thanks. I have been trying to find the solution since two days. I'm liking Knockout so far.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `ko.applyBindings()`'s painting is not synchronous when you use `ko.options.deferUpdates = true;`. So for example if you try to get an `svg.getCTM()` directly afterwards it won't work as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this through a custom binding:
That way your "external code" can be more integrated with your data binding. You will also have support for updating if necessary.

Read more about the concept here
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html